# Lines between code in android

Tags: android

Is giving line space between two lines of java code or xml code will increase the memory size of app?

Example:

```
    ImageButton sum = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.sum);


    ImageButton numberMatch = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.numberMatch);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you compile your code to build your app, it all gets transformed into bytecode, which is the representation that the Android device understands how to execute. Only information that's needed for the bytecode is left intact at this point. That means that any blank lines, and even any comments, are stripped out of your Java source code.

Answer (score 2):

No, it will not. Compiler will ignore blank lines.

Answer (score 1):

No its not Taken  memory of appliaction. [Refer Here Manage  App's Memory](https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/memory.html) they mention what will be taken app memory during the Run progress..